# what are few options to start a fargate job?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am setting up a aws fargate job via cloudformation ( see sample below). based on some questions in stack overflow, there are few options to trigger/start this fargate job, via CRON set up. lot of the questions around this are old. so wanted to see if there are updates  around this. can a existing fargate job hooked up to a lambda or a s3 object creation event to start the job?

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: An example CloudFormation template for Fargate.
Parameters:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC::Id
  SubnetA:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
  SubnetB:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Subnet::Id
  Certificate:
    Type: String
    Default: 'arn:aws:acm:region:123456789012:certificate/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
  Image:
    Type: String
    Default: 123456789012.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/image:tag
Resources:
  Cluster:
    Type: AWS::ECS::Cluster
    Properties:
      ClusterName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, Cluster]]
  TaskDefinition:
    Type: AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition
    DependsOn: LogGroup
    Properties:
      Family: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, TaskDefinition]]
      NetworkMode: awsvpc
      RequiresCompatibilities:
        - FARGATE
      Cpu: 256
      Memory: 2GB
      ExecutionRoleArn: !Ref ExecutionRole
      TaskRoleArn: !Ref TaskRole
      ContainerDefinitions:
        - Name: !Ref ServiceName
          Image: !Ref Image

  # A role needed by ECS
  ExecutionRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, ExecutionRole]]
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - 'arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy'
  # A role for the containers
  TaskRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: !Join ['', [!Ref ServiceName, TaskRole]]
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: 'sts:AssumeRole'
```

Answer (score 1):

> "so wanted to see if there are updates around this. can a existing
> fargate job hooked up to a lambda or a s3 object creation event to
> start the job?"

You can (and have always been able to) trigger an ECS Fargate task from AWS Lambda. You would just [call the AWS ECS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_RunTask.html) inside Lambda, using the AWS SDK for the programming language you are writing the Lambda function in.

For S3 object creation, you could do this using [AWS Event Bridge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/EventBridge.html). There is an [official tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/CloudWatch-Events-tutorial-ECS.html) on this, although it's a bit sparse on details. You would want to look into using the Container Overrides setting to pass the S3 object details into the ECS task.

Comment: thanks. I am going through the links you have provided. I am working on cloudformation template to do all this. from the link, i can see we will have to create a cloudwatch event rule , which I suppose get triggered when object is created in s3 and which in turns invokes the fargate task.

Comment: Yes that is correct.